# Почему при подключении гугл шрифтов из локальной папки получаю дырки в буквах на сайте?

Tags: css, шрифты, google-fonts

На сайте подключаю **google fonts** [шрифт Roboto Condensed] из локальной папки и получаю шрифт с дырками в некоторых буквах как в кириллице, так и в латинице. Почему так и как это исправить?

P.S. Думал вопрос с конвертацией самих шрифтов, но если оставлять в стилях единственный изначальный формат `.woff2`, то разницы нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Roboto Condensed'), local('RobotoCondensed'),
  url(../../fonts/RobotoCondensed-cyrillic.otf) format('opentype'),
  url(../../fonts/RobotoCondensed-cyrillic.ttf) format('truetype'),
  url(../../fonts/RobotoCondensed-cyrillic.woff) format('woff'),
  url(../../fonts/RobotoCondensed-cyrillic.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0301, U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Roboto Condensed'), local('RobotoCondensed'),
  url(../../fonts/RobotoCondensed-latin.otf) format('opentype'),
  url(../../fonts/RobotoCondensed-latin.ttf) format('truetype'),
  url(../../fonts/RobotoCondensed-latin.woff) format('woff'),
  url(../../fonts/RobotoCondensed-latin.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Comment: откуда вы взяли эти шрифты?

Comment: @Alexey Ten скачал с гугл фонтс, прогнал через конвертер и в результате тип `opentype` оказался косячным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас порядок шрифтов подключения - не правильный. Надо - от современных подключать к менее затребованым. Да и в 2024 уже можно оставить `woff2` `woff`. Возможно ваша версия браузера уже не умеет те форматы подтягивать корректно.

PS Вы уверены что у вас на локалке нормальная версия `src: local('Roboto Condensed')` стоит ?

Comment: Да @BlackStar1991 тоже стал параллельно проверять на локалке и внутри самих шрифтов - и оказалось, что тип `opentype` был закоцаный, а вот `truetype` в порядке. Попробовал для теста несколько раз прогнать через конвертер и каждый раз opentype кривой, а truetype нормальный. Странно, но ладно.. Спасибо!